# Implement multiple instances of Bitmap Game object

Tags: android, random, bitmap, android-canvas

I'm a beginner at Android Development.

I've created a game. One Bitmap (1) is controllable, the other bitmap (2) acts on collision with the first. Works fine. Question ; How would I create multiple instances of (2) that would, to start with, all respond to a collision with (1) in the same way.

What I've built so far;

In the MainGamePanel, I create the two Bitmaps :

```
  basket = new basket(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.basket01), 50, 50);
  apple = new apple(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.apple_red01));
```

The MainThread performs update and draws the canvas on the panel

In the update (in MainGamePanel), I check for collisions between (1) and (2), checking the coordinates.

If collision detected, I set coordinates on apple (2), it becomes 'slotted'.

Then, if apple (2) is slotted AND touched, I move it to a random position on the screen and set the boolean slotted to false.

... this is where I'm stuck, 2 questions (should I split them up here on SO?)

1. How would I create multiple instances of the bitmap (2)?
2. How would I get the X and Y max values of the canvas, or view that is not created within the class itself?

Thanks!

Current Code-snippets for the bitmap (2) "apple" :

```
     public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
  canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, X - width/2, Y - height/2, null);
 }
```

With regards to question two (review random generator, I need to set max values);

```
    if (slotted){
     if (eventX >= (X - width/ 2) && (eventX <= (X + width/2))) {
           if (eventY >= (Y - height/ 2) && (eventY <= (Y + height/ 2))) {
    // basket touch
    Random Rnd = new Random();

    float nX=Rnd.nextInt(HOWTOMAXOFVIEWORCANVAS);
    float nY=Rnd.nextInt(HOWTOMAXOFVIEWORCANVAS)+80; 

// the +80 is to prevent the apple from returning in the 'slotted' area (the basket can't get there ;)

    setX(nX);
    setY(nY);
    slotted = false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way would be to create a `list` of apples instead of separate apple instances:

```
ArrayList<apple> appleList = new ArrayList<apple>();
int nApples = 5;
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
      appleList.add(new apple();
```

You **DO NOT WANT** want to create multiple instances of a bitmap. Bitmaps can consume a large amount of memory 4 bytes per pixel. Its would be many times better to simply create the bitmap once and then just have your apple objects reference that bitmap directly.

The max X and Y values of the canvas are determined by the dimensions of the `View` you are drawing to. Once your `View` has been inflated and drawn you should be able to get those values from the view.

Comment: With regards to viewsize; I've tried adding  public int sizeY = getHeight(); to the MainGamePanel (extends SurfaceView). However, when I call MainGamePanel.sizeY from the apple class, I get errors about static and non-static references. the getDefaultSize method also doesn't seem much help. Could you elaborate on how to implement the dimensions of a SurfaceView in a different class?

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I solved my Question 2. In MainGamePanel, I created a public static int width.. later, when I am sure the canvas has been drawn, I fill it with : width = getWidth();. Then, I can access MainGamePanel.width from within another class! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I solved my Question 1. I use 'for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
 apple nextApple = new apple(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.apple_red01));
 AppleList.add(nextApple);
 }' And can access the different apples by their position in the array.

Thanks! Voting up.

Comment: Slayton, thanks to your answer I was able to write https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=happyworx.nl.Applez . Thank you!